# Coldfusion - .cfm file not found when it exists on the server

Tags: coldfusion

About 10x a day we are getting a file not found error in our Coldfusion application logs for files that EXIST on the server. The specific error is

```
"File not found: /rewrite.cfm The specific sequence of files included or processed is: '''' "
```

and the stack trace:

```
coldfusion.runtime.TemplateNotFoundException: File not found: /rewrite.cfm
    at coldfusion.filter.PathFilter.invoke(PathFilter.java:69)
    at coldfusion.filter.ExceptionFilter.invoke(ExceptionFilter.java:70)
    at coldfusion.filter.ClientScopePersistenceFilter.invoke(ClientScopePersistenceFilter.java:28)
    at coldfusion.filter.BrowserFilter.invoke(BrowserFilter.java:38)
    at coldfusion.filter.NoCacheFilter.invoke(NoCacheFilter.java:46)
    at coldfusion.filter.GlobalsFilter.invoke(GlobalsFilter.java:38)
    at coldfusion.filter.DatasourceFilter.invoke(DatasourceFilter.java:22)
    at coldfusion.filter.CachingFilter.invoke(CachingFilter.java:62)
    at coldfusion.CfmServlet.service(CfmServlet.java:200)
    at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapServlet.service(BootstrapServlet.java:89)
    at jrun.servlet.FilterChain.doFilter(FilterChain.java:86)
    at coldfusion.monitor.event.MonitoringServletFilter.doFilter(MonitoringServletFilter.java:42)
    at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapFilter.doFilter(BootstrapFilter.java:46)
    at jrun.servlet.FilterChain.doFilter(FilterChain.java:94)
    at jrun.servlet.FilterChain.service(FilterChain.java:101)
    at jrun.servlet.ServletInvoker.invoke(ServletInvoker.java:106)
    at jrun.servlet.JRunInvokerChain.invokeNext(JRunInvokerChain.java:42)
    at jrun.servlet.JRunRequestDispatcher.invoke(JRunRequestDispatcher.java:286)
    at jrun.servlet.ServletEngineService.dispatch(ServletEngineService.java:543)
    at jrun.servlet.jrpp.JRunProxyService.invokeRunnable(JRunProxyService.java:203)
    at jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$DownstreamMetrics.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:320)
    at jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$ThreadThrottle.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:428)
    at jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$UpstreamMetrics.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:266)
    at jrunx.scheduler.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:66)
```

Our server environment:

- Ubuntu 10.04 LTS
- Coldfusion 9.01
- CFWheels

While this is happening relatively few times compared with the number of requests we are serving, this is still something I would like to figure out.

Has anyone seen this error before and can you tell me why Coldfusion randomly decides that the files is not there?

Thanks.

Comment: Since you are on Ubuntu, just wanted to make sure that the actual file is lower-cased. I doubt that is the cause since you said it works most of the time.

Comment: The other thing that you will want to check is that the user that jrun (if you are using the built in server for CF) has proper permissions to the file.  I can't remember them off the top of my head, but they are probably something like 664. (RWRWR)

Comment: I had a similar issue and restarting the Coldfusion server fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

When I put wheels in a subdirectory I had to edit the .htaccess file and make sure that the sub directory name was in the rewrite rules.

Another time I saw this was when someone went to a domain name that wasn't in Apache so it would go to the default website and throw a weird error like that.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using Apache name-based Virtual Hosts? Requests that hit the ColdFusion server by another URL (say http://localhost) will not necessarily find files in the root of a name-based vhost. I'll sometimes run into this with CF Scheduled Tasks that get set up pointing to localhost.

Can you line up the actual request in your Apache logs with the offending one in your CF logs?

Answer (score 1):

Unless you've changed it, "/" is an aliased directory in CF.  In Windows, IIRC, this points to the document root specified in the installation process (unless modified), and I assume it is similar for Linux systems.  My guess is that one of two things is happening:

- CFWheels expects to be installed in the root directory, and isn't (or / isn't pointed at the install location for CFWheels)
- You are trying to use / to point to a directory that is not the one aliased in CF

Try making sure that / is pointed to the colder with the missing template in the CF Administrator.

Comment: Wheels is installed correctly and is at the root of the site. 99.9% of our request are finding the /rewrite.cfm file. But randomly, CF cannot find this file and throw there error above.

Answer (score 1):

We ran into a similiar issue.  For us, we were running into the limit on the number of open files.

You can run:
`ulimit -Hn`
and
`ulimit -Sn`
to see the current limits for the relevant user.

Modify /etc/security/limits.conf to update the open files limit.

Answer (score 0):

What about leaving trusted cache off for awhile, and make sure you can access the file.

Or clear the cache, and make sure the template is accessible.

Comment: Truste cache is not turned on for the server.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I reference a file on a server, unless it's in a specific directory that gets hard-coded for some reason, I use ExpandPath... for example:

```
<cffile action="read" file="#ExpandPath('.')#/myfile.txt">
```

This assumes the file is in the same directory as the currently-executing template.